# Laravel - Maintenance mode just for some urls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to use the `Maintenance mode` using the artisan command `"down"`, but just for some urls...

In my case, i want that all urls that starts with `"/admin/*"` continue working.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to create a middleware and check if the URL starts with `admin` or not. However I'm not going to do all the hard work for you. Please try yourself and come back to this question if you encounter a problem you can't solve yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest by `@lukasgeiter` I created a middleware that tests my url...
That`s my code:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class Maintanance {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if($request->is('admin*') || $request->is('maintanance')){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return new RedirectResponse(url('/maintanance'));
        }
    }
}
```

After that I created a `route` that show de maintenance view:

```
Route::get('maintanance', function(){
    return view('errors.503');
});
```

Now I can call the command `"up"` and the application still under maintenance, but the `/admin` urls...

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at `app/http/middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php`
There is a URI Array:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode as Middleware;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be reachable while maintenance mode is enabled.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

array-example :

```
    protected $except = [
        'api/customers',
        'api/user'
    ];
```

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted, but this is actually the native answer. If you, as given in the example, extend the original middleware, then override the `$except` array to add the routes you require to be accessible after `artisan down` is executed.

Comment: not working if routes has parameters though (just tried on Laravel 8.21.0

Comment: How do you use Parameters? Did you try to use wildcards in the $except array like "/admin/*"? Can you provide an example route?

Comment: In 8.x and later, it's `PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before, but not using the `php artisan down` command.

The first thing the kernel does before even loading the application is checking if your site is in maintenance mode.

So, you won't be able to reach your controller or even your routes with `php artisan down`.

You might want to do your own command like`php artisan softdown` which create a file somewhere in your /storage dir which will tell to your app the app is in 'soft down' mode. And of course, make another one called `softup`

Then, in your routes, you'll wrap all your frontend routes with an IF which checks if the file exists, or not.

If so, then you return the view maintenance.blade.php.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using this to check if any of the URL segments is API, to let those URL's to work properly.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() &&  !in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],['192.168.240.18','127x.0.0.1'])) {

        /** if URL contains API, disable continue, don't keep maintenance */
        if(in_array('api',$request->segments())){
            return $next($request);
        }

        throw new HttpException(503);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```